где взять параметр system_version в конструктор класса TelegramClient
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash,
                        system_version='4.16.30-vxCUSTOM')

Как узнать system_version, device_model, app_version в конструктор класса TelegramClient?
ссылка на ответ, где это используется

Источники дефолтных значений параметров есть в документации:

system_version = platform.uname().release
device_model = platform.uname().machine
app_version = telethon.version.__version__

В указанном ответе говорится о том, что нужно указать свои параметры, которые будут отличаться от значений по умолчанию. То есть, какие-нибудь произвольные (все они типа str):
client = TelegramClient(
    phone, api_id, api_hash,
    system_version='1.2.3-zxc-custom',
    device_model='aboba-linux-custom',
    app_version='1.0.1'
 )

